# Makefile.am conditional test

Tags: makefile

I usually add to my home-made Makefile the following:

```
ifeq ($(shell uname -m),armv7l)
ADDITIONAL := -mfpu=neon
endif
```

How can I do the same in a Makefile.am file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a post that basically answers my question: http://wcang.blogspot.com/2008/05/conditional-compilation-based-on-target.html. So the solution is:

`configure.ac`:

```
AM_CONDITIONAL(ARM, test `uname -m` = "armv7l")
```

`Makefile.am`:

```
if ARM
NEON=-mfpu=neon
else
NEON=
endif
```